# Extracting multiple numerical values from a carriage return-separated list in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table filled with cells formatted like this:

```
---(cell)---
3 x item
2 x another item
299 x yet another item
       (... - variable amount of items here)
4 x the last item in this cell
---(end of cell)---
```

All items are separated with carriage returns (`=CHAR(10)`).

I need to extract the numbers and do various operations on them according to the item type. I'll take it one problem at a time and try to extract the numbers first. I'd use MID but it doesn't help with finding "the first set of numerical characters after a carriage return".

Any idea?

Comment: Are the numbers always at the start of each carriage return and always followed by a single space followed by an "x"? Where do you want them returned? In separate cells to the right of each entry?

Comment: Yes, they're always at the start of each carriage return, as exemplified. The problem is that they're not separate cells. They're lists in a single cell. What I need to do is stuff like "sum all numbers", "sum all item A", "sum all item B" etc. For now I want to learn how to extract them in a cell next to this one as, say "3,2,299,(...),4"

Comment: If you want them all returned into a single cell, e.g. comma-separated, then you'll require VBA. If you were content to have them each in separate cells, e.g. to the right of each of your entries, then this could be achieved using worksheet formulas alone.

Comment: Like I said, they're not separate entries, that's the headache :( so I can't extract each of them separately... oh wait, maybe I can extract N numbers from a single cell into N rows next to that cell?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a collection of formulas that will get you started. I have the cell to analyze as A1, and table of analysis results in B7:I11. The columns B-I are Item#, Start, End, SubString, Delim, Quantity and Item.

First, you can count the number of s in your cell

```
nCRs:     =LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(10),""))
```

The number of items is the number of CRs plus 1:

```
nItems:   =LEN($A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(10),""))+1
```

Note: to use the same tools on all items, I'm adding a CR to the beginning and end of the string. That way I'm always extracting sub-strings that are CR-delimited. To get the first item, put a 1 in B7:

```
B7: 1
```

To get the start of the first sub-string, use SEARCH with start pos = 1

```
C7: =SEARCH(CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&$A$1&CHAR(10),1)
```

Similarly get the end of the first sub-string with SEARCH starting to the right of where the first CR was found

```
D7: =SEARCH(CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&$A$1&CHAR(10),C7+1)
```

Now use MID to extract the text between two

```
E7: =MID(CHAR(10)&$A$1&CHAR(10),C7+1,D7-C7)
```

In F7 I have delimiter text (between item count and item description), assumed to be " x ":

```
F7: =" x "
```

In G7 find the location of the delimiter

```
G7: =SEARCH(F7,E7,1)
```

In H7 extract the text left of the delimiter (item count) and convert to a number

```
H7: =VALUE(LEFT(E7,G7-1))
```

In I7 extract the item description

```
I7: =RIGHT(E7,LEN(E7)-G7-LEN(F7)+1)
```

To get the second (and subsequent) items, start the search for CR where the last CR was found. So in C8

```
C8: =SEARCH(CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&$A$1&CHAR(10),D7)
```

Fill the formulas down to complete the table.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes data with text string containing multiple items per cell and separated by carriage returns is located in Sheet1 at `B6:C11` as shown in figure 1 *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*.

[image]

*Fig. 1*

Objective as presented by OP:

> I need to extract the numbers and do various operations on them
>   according to the item type. I'll take it one problem at a time and try
>   to extract the numbers first.
>
> Yes, they're (numbers) always at the start of each carriage return, as
>   exemplified.  What I need to do is stuff like "sum all numbers", "sum
>   all item A", "sum all item B" etc.

*This solution proposes a review the objectives in order to first work on the extraction of the items to create a table with all items, after this is achieved then all other goals can be workout in a simpler manner.*

- First we add a column to the data in `Sheet1`. Enter this formula in `C7` and copy till last record.

  ```
  =SUM(1+LEN($B7),-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B7,CHAR(10),"")))
  ```
- Let’s create in `Sheet2` a table to extract the items from the data in the `Sheet1`.

The extraction table is located at `B6:G55` and contains the following items (see Fig. 2):

**Itm.Nbr**(+) : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
=IF( OR( B6 = SUM( Sheet1!$C$6:$C$11 ), B6 = "" ), "",
- 1 + ROWS( B$6:B7 ) )
```

**Line**(+) : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
=IF( EXACT( C6, C$6 ), 2,
IF( $B7 = "", "",
IF( $B7 <= SUM( INDEX( Sheet1!$C$6:$C$11, 1 ) : INDEX( Sheet1!$C$6:$C$11, C6 ) ), C6,
SUM( 1, C6 ) ) ) )
```

**Itm.Lne**(+) : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
= IF( EXACT( D$6, D6 ), 1,
IF( $B7 = "", "",
IF( $C7 = $C6, SUM( 1, D6 ), 1 ) ) )
```

**Extracted Lines**(+) : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
=IF( $B7 = "", "",
CLEAN( IF( $D7 = 1,
LEFT( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ),
FIND( CHAR(10), INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ) ) ),
MID( LEFT( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ) & CHAR(10),
SEARCH( CHAR(135), SUBSTITUTE( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ) & CHAR(10), CHAR(10), CHAR(135), $D7 ) ) ),
SEARCH( CHAR(135), SUBSTITUTE( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ), CHAR(10), CHAR(135), - 1 + $D7 ) ), LEN( INDEX( Sheet1!$B$6:$B$11, $C7 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

**Item** : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
=IF( $B7 = "", "",
IFERROR( MID( $E7, 3 + SEARCH( " x ", $E7 ), LEN( $E7 ) ), "!Err" ) )
```

**Qty** : Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

```
=IF( $B7 = "", "",
IFERROR( --TRIM( LEFT( $E7, FIND( " ", $E7 ) ) ), "!Err" ) )
```

*(+) This working fields can be hidden*

[image]

*Fig. 2*